# Computing the values of a, b and c that minimis a set of input values

Tags: r

Assume that I have the following data

I want to create a minimisation of the following formula.

[image]

How can I replicate this using minimisation in R - the S values in the formula correspond to the `S_2` column and the V values correspond to the `V_discounted_to_year2`

Data

```
library(tidyverse)

r = 0.06
K = 1.10
t = 3
stock_prices = data.frame(
  S_0 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  S_1 = c(1.09, 1.16, 1.22, 0.93, 1.11, 0.76, 0.92, 0.88),
  S_2 = c(1.08, 1.26, 1.07, 0.97, 1.56, 0.77, 0.84, 1.22),
  S_3 = c(1.34, 1.54, 1.03, 0.92, 1.52, 0.90, 1.01, 1.34)
)

payoffs = data.frame( # P here means "put" since we are analysing a put option
  P_0 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  P_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  P_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  P_3 = c(0, 0, 0.07, 0.18, 0, 0.20, 0.09, 0)
)

data = stock_prices %>% 
  bind_cols(payoffs) %>% 
  mutate(
    monniness = ifelse(S_2 < K, "in_the_money", "out_the_money"),
    V_discounted_to_year2 = ifelse(monniness == "in_the_money", P_3* exp(-r * (t-2)), 0) # we are just discounding 1 period so we set t-2
  )
```

Edit 1:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can estimate this with least squares regression.  From the detail in the question you want to include rows 1,3,4,6 and 7 in the calculation.  So:

```
> lm(data=data[c(1,3,4,6,7),] , V_discounted_to_year2 ~ S_2 + I(S_2^2))

Call:
lm(formula = V_discounted_to_year2 ~ S_2 + I(S_2^2), data = data[c(1, 
    3, 4, 6, 7), ])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          S_2           s2  
     -1.070        2.983       -1.814
```

This matches the estimates in the book.

If you want the predicted values:

```r
> lm(data=data[c(1,3,4,6,7),] , V_discounted_to_year2 ~ S_2 + I(S_2^2) |> predict()
         1          3          4          6          7 
0.03674056 0.04589834 0.11752682 0.15196921 0.15641792
```

These aren't quite the same as quoted, I guess a rounding error somewhere.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought but I am not getting the same output as the authors `a = -1.070`, `b = 2.983` and `c = -1.813`

Comment: @user113156 you have a different number of data points to start with. there are five in the equation posted, and eight in the dataset. so its not obvious which points are being used.

Comment: Ah sorry, the example comes from the book `options, futures and other derivatives Global edition 11e - John C HUll` page 662. Basically, if the column contains a zero its not used in the calculation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OLS is the answer here, you should probably check your calculations.  There are four non-zero V rows.

Comment: You are right the section of the chapter is called "The Least-Squares Approach" - its taken from the paper `Valuing American Options by Simulation: A Simple Least-Squares Approach ` - I just can't seem to replicate the results.

Comment: I added an editt o give more context of the question

Comment: @user113156 It matches if you use the correct rows (based on the quoted S2 values)